# Laravel 4.2 custom Observer Event

Tags: events, laravel, laravel-4, observers

I have a directory under my app folder named observers and I listen for various events such as created , updated , ... and I handle them !
my observer events bootstrap is in my model boot function !
for example I have User Model under models folder and I have UserObserver under observers folder!
now I need to add my specific event to eloquent observer ! consider I want fire event when one column such as "enable" of my user table has changed.
I know I should extend eloquent Model and add a function like userchangestate()
coz I already have looked up Eloquent Model it has a function for every event ('creating' , 'created' , 'saving' , 'saved' , ....)
but still I'm not sure how handle it !
thanks !

Comment: So you're looking for a way to fire an event when a specific column value has changed, not just that the model is saving/saved etc?

Comment: Ok good, see answer below ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that my comment above is true having read the question a number of times to try and make sense of it.

I would do this by checking if an attribute is `dirty` (changed) during the saving event and firing a custom event if it has changed with it's new value.

In your observer class dependency inject the dispatcher (the IoC will do this for you automatically).

```
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;

class UserObserver {

    protected $events;

    public function __construct(Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->events = $dispatcher;

        // Set up a listener for your modified event to run a method
        // on this class
        $this->events->listen('myevent.modified', [$this, 'changeState']);
    }

    public function saving($model)
    {
        if ($model->isDirty(['attribute'])
        {
            $this->events->fire('myevent.modified', [$model->attribute]);
        }
    }

    public function changeState($value)
    {
        // Handle your event here
    }
}
```

You can now listen to this event anywhere using the signature `myevent.modified`.

*Edit* Added in a listener to the constructor and pushed the event callback to the `changeState` method.

If you don't need an event fired you could just push the result straight through.

```
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;

class UserObserver {

    protected $events;

    public function __construct(Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->events = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function saving($model)
    {
        if ($model->isDirty(['attribute'])
        {
            $this->changeState($model->attribute);
        }
    }

    public function changeState($value)
    {
        // Handle your event here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks David ! for giving me your time ! much appriciated ! first I had a error which was :  Argument 1 passed to NewsObserver::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Events\Dispatch                                           and when I passed Dispatch object to observe function in my model in boot function It worked ! I just want my observer class to have a method called "changestate" just like "created" , "saved" , .. which  catch event and handle it ! is it possible?? thanks again!

Comment: Sure it's possible, added in the way to do it to the example above!

Comment: That worked like a charm  for me!  thanks very much ! of course you know much about laravel. where should I read about laravel dispatcher??

Comment: Tbh. I just read the source code. The dispatcher class is what's used by the static faced 'Event' so 'Event::fire('blah')' is using the dispatcher. Maybe consider accepting the answer for me? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David I got my answer:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;

class News extends Magniloquent {

    protected $fillable = [];
    public $table = 'news';

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        News::observe(new NewsObserver(new Dispatcher));
    }
}
```

And my observer is as below:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;

class NewsObserver
{
    protected $events;

    public function __construct(Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->events = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function saving($model)
    {
        if ($model->isDirty(['publish']))
        {
            $this->changeState($model->publish);
        }
    }   

    public function changeState($value)
    {
       //do my stuff
    }
}
```

And this works for me!

When the `publish` column changes in my `news` table the `NewsObserver::changeState()` event is fired automatically.